# setTimeout() is not calling function after specified time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code in my js file.

```
function makeScrollable(wrapper, scrollable){  
    ...
    // Hide images until they are not loaded
    scrollable.hide();

    var loading = $('<div class="loading">Loading...</div>').appendTo(wrapper);

    // Set function that will check if all images are loaded
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        var images = scrollable.find('img');
        var completed = 0;

        if (completed == images.length) {
            clearInterval(interval);

            // Timeout added to fix problem with Chrome
            setTimeout(function(){
                loading.hide();
                ....
            }, 1000); //end of setTimeout(func, delay)

        } //end of if (completed == images.length)

    }, 100); //end of var interval = setInterval(fn, 100)

    ...
}

(function(){
    makeScrollable("div.sc_menu_wrapper", "div.sc_menu");
})(jQuery);
```

But my timeout function isn't calling. I am still getting the loading Div. Function should be call after 1 sec, which hide the loading div and execute code after. But it isn't happening. What i am doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Does the if condition `if (completed == images.length)` return true..?

Comment: yes, it comes to clearInterval(), as well as setTimeOut() function. I saw it while debugging with firebug, but function isn't calling :(

Comment: I am not sure about that, but leave alone the debugging try putting an alert in the `setTimeout` function see whether it pops up something or not!!!

Comment: no i put the alert in the setTimeout function but it is not calling

Comment: post a bit of live code showing the same so that can be seen....try [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)  for posting

Comment: on JSFiddle it is working, but when i open page on my browser, then code is not working????? I simple  copy paste the code on JSFiddle. Why it is working there and not on my browser???? Amazing. Anyways can you tell me after saving jSFiddle how can i tell you people that check the JSFiddle. I don't know how to use JSFiddle with this forum.Thanks

Comment: just post the url of the code that you are currently editing

Comment: I told you that on JSFiddle it is working. I am using netbeans IDE, may be it's IDE issue, or ... i don't know..Anyways i am putting the code outside setTimeout(). So i can check the working. Thanks. But one thing code is right, there's nothing wrond with the code. I check it out and then let you people know. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong position of code.

```
    var completed = 0;

    if (completed == images.length) {  // This will be true only when there are no images
        clearInterval(interval);


        setTimeout(function(){
            loading.hide();
            ....
        }, 1000); 

    }
```

put it outside

```
var completed = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    var images = scrollable.find('img');


    if (completed == images.length) {
        clearInterval(interval);

        // Timeout added to fix problem with Chrome
        setTimeout(function(){
            loading.hide();
            ....
        }, 1000); //end of setTimeout(func, delay)

    } //end of if (completed == images.length)

}, 100); //end of var interval = setInterval(fn, 100)
```

And hope you are incrementing `completed` somewhere in the code

Comment: i am incrementing the completed just before the line `if (completed == images.length) {..}` Here what i am doing `var completed = 0;->images.each(function(){if (this.complete) {completed++}}); -> if (completed == images.length) {..} ` . And i am getting true, it comes to check, clear the interval, comes to setTimeout function, but didn't execute it..

Comment: I would suggest you to share complete code.. If possible make a demo in http://jsfiddle.net